# How to get fast response in Afhttpsessionmanager?

Tags: objective-c

I am using Afhttpsessionmanager to get the data from server. but data comes very slow. how to get fast response data from server.  Can you help anyone for this?

Comment: Why have you totally changed the question?

Comment: i edit my question.sorry kindly tell me the answer

Comment: You should have posted another question because the previous question was regarding UITableView code in Swift and this is altogether a different question.

Comment: but currently im not unable to post the question. so only.

Comment: this question is regarding network speed, and I dont think it has anything to do with afhttpsessionmanager at all

Comment: This is 100% network, the lag between  Afhttpsessionmanager and lower level calls on this is insignificant. At least not something Humans would notice.

Answer (score 2):

Fast Response data from server doesnt have to do with `AFHTTPSessionManager`. It is used for bringing the data from API call to your device, the slow response have to do with slow network connection, slow server, huge data called from server within a single call etc.

Answer (score 0):

Friend for response speed i am sure its depend on on your Backend configurations. I have faced the same problem because of my backend configurations are low & once backend configurations upgraded everything works fine. Same talk with your backend developer & tell him to optimize queries too(i.e Backend code) .